# SD Card not working

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, external-sd

I have bought a new samsung 16 GB yesterday. and installed Froyo. I plug my 4 Gb SD card which I was using in my previous Nokia Cell Phone. but SGS is not picking it up. I detached it and put it back in Nokia its working. can anyone tell me whats the problem. any difference in file system.??

Thanks & Regards
Imran Zaidi

Comment: As Ryan asked, are you getting any errors upon inserting the card?  Is reformatting the card an option?

Answer (score 3):

Does it say that it does not recognize the sdcard? Where are you looking to see if it detects the sdcard?

for froyo on the SGS, i believe the sdcard is mounted to /sdcard/external_sd (that's where mine is anyhow)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what file system your old phone used as Nokia use a few different phone OS (Linux, Symbian Series 40, 60 & 80 and possibly others), but Android will read a standard FAT32 file system on an SD card, which is what most phones use.

A lot of Nokia phones have the option to password protect or encrypt the SD card, it's very easy to forget you've done that, and Android won't be able to read the card if you've done that. I can remember swapping an SD between my ancient non-feature-phone Nokia and a friend's almost identical model and not being able to work out why it wouldn't work in his phone, until I remembered that I'd set a PIN number on the card.

The easiest way round this is probably to put the card in the Nokia phone, copy the entire contents on to a PC, then plug it into your Android phone, format it, and then copy the contents back (if you want to keep the contents).